# .on click event not always working on dynamically added table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a table with dynamically added table rows and a jquery code to add .on click event on rows with specific class. The point is that the code is working great, but only sometimes... 80% of the debug sessions when I mouseover the table row the mouse starts flickering and the event works after 20 clicks on the row.

Table:

```
<div id="main-tbl">
    <table id="tbl" class="table">
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#tbl").on("click", "tr", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

rows are added via ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.aspx/GetData',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            var newdata = data.d;
            $tbl.empty();
            $tbl.append('<tr><th>Test</th></tr>');
            var rows = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                rows.push('<tr><td>newdata[i].Test</td></tr>');
            }
            $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
        }
    }
});
```

The base is asp.net using signalr+ajax to load data from sqldb.

Does anyone have any ideas why is it working only sometimes?

-Alexander

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) Use `$("#tbl").on("click", "tr", function () {
     alert("test");
 });`

Comment: I used that too, the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Satpals answer:

```js
$("#tbl").on("click", "tr", function() {
  $("#tbl").append('<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
  console.log($(this).index());
  //alert("test");
});
```

```html
<div id="main-tbl">
  <table id="tbl" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>New!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the code and how it works but the point is that the table is not responding 80% of the debug sessions

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on dynamically created row then code should be like this.

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function () {
  alert("test");
});
```